# Combining/Joining/merging 2 dataframes, one containing raw data and other, the weights

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, join, dataframe, merge

So I am currently trying to combine/merge or join two dataframes in the sense that the columns get combined and become into one hierarchical column.

Lets say I have the two dataframes here:

```
series1 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(10))
series2 = pd.Series(np.random.rand(10))
df = pd.DataFrame({'Normal': series1, 'Uniform': series2})
df_wgts = df.div(df.sum(0))
```

The second dataframe gives me weights. Now I want to join/combine (or whatever it takes) them to form a hierarchical column Like down below

```
Out[3]: 
     Normal             Uniform          
       data   weights      data   weights
0 -1.407268  0.569645  0.985227  0.162974
1 -1.551743  0.628126  0.561975  0.092961
2  0.428825 -0.173583  0.258784  0.042807
3  1.453088 -0.588192  0.868771  0.143711
4 -2.037619  0.824803  0.624250  0.103262
5 -0.119474  0.048362  0.947331  0.156706
6 -0.661711  0.267852  0.691038  0.114310
7 -0.371787  0.150495  0.608671  0.100685
8  1.987500 -0.804515  0.326396  0.053992
9 -0.190243  0.077008  0.172842  0.028591
```

IS there a simple way to do that? I actually had to slice each column on the dataframes to get this output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) + [`swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) + [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
print (pd.concat([df, df_wgts], axis=1, keys=['data','weights'])
         .swaplevel(0,1,axis=1)
         .sort_index(axis=1))
     Normal             Uniform          
       data   weights      data   weights
0  1.315780  0.300954  0.816827  0.144410
1  0.296063  0.067717  0.068083  0.012037
2 -0.107585 -0.024608  0.621109  0.109808
3  1.564411  0.357822  0.608546  0.107587
4  0.714840  0.163503  0.454494  0.080352
5  0.778800  0.178132  0.881340  0.155815
6  0.559171  0.127897  0.126216  0.022314
7  1.165832  0.266657  0.881383  0.155823
8 -1.735812 -0.397026  0.521863  0.092262
9 -0.179464 -0.041048  0.676453  0.119593
```

Comment: You're a savior!